# Live statistics chess960 from chess.com?

Tags: chess, recommendations, statistics, chess960

Both [lichess](https://lichess.org/) and chess.com have the feature to play the variant [chess960](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fischer_random_chess) live. However, only lichess has a graph showing how your live chess960 rating has changed over time. Lichess also shows other statistics like highest, lowest, best wins, worst losses, average opponent rating, etc. (chess.com does have this for correspondence chess960 though.)

I could create my own graph and statistics in Excel/Google Sheets by manually recording each game's date and my rating afterwards indicated beside my username, but...

**Question**: Is there a way to obtain, or what in general is the way to go about obtaining, ratings after each chess960 game using some kind of script that sees a player's public profile and then extracts the data?

I have a feeling this kind of script has been done before even if this was not specifically done for chess.com's live chess960. The script doesn't have to graph (pretty easy to do once you have to the data: just use excel/google sheets). I just need the script to collect all the dates and rating numbers for each line of the user's games.

---

Update 2: Fixed now. see the 'json' vs the 'preformed'. WOW.

Update 1: It appears Mike Steelson has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345784/how-do-convert-parse-extract-data-from-a-pgn-into-a-spreadsheet-google-sheet-exc), where the code is given as

```
=arrayformula( regexextract(split( substitute(substitute(substitute(getDataJSON(A1;"/games";"/pgn");"[";"");"]";"");"""";"") ;char(10));"\s.*") )
```

with an example given here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MX1o5qdy0K3gTMzbimUV3SmFf-0XPCSJ8Vz4IjI-8Ak/copy

It appears there's a problem when it gets to the case of chess960 only. Consider for example [this player](https://www.chess.com/member/dukov5): Replacing 'gmwso' with the player's username will yield a weird output. i imagine the output will be messier for mixed chess960 and chess.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://superuser.com/q/1645900/93541, https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/54692/8191, https://chess.stackexchange.com/q/34842/12996, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67159513/781723.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because cross posted at https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/34842/live-statistics-chess960-from-chess-com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Update 2: Fixed now. see the 'json' vs the 'preformed'. WOW.

Update 1: It appears Mike Steelson has an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67345784/how-do-convert-parse-extract-data-from-a-pgn-into-a-spreadsheet-google-sheet-exc), where the code is given as

```
=arrayformula( regexextract(split( substitute(substitute(substitute(getDataJSON(A1;"/games";"/pgn");"[";"");"]";"");"""";"") ;char(10));"\s.*") )
```

with an example given here

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MX1o5qdy0K3gTMzbimUV3SmFf-0XPCSJ8Vz4IjI-8Ak/copy

It appears there's a problem when it gets to the case of chess960 only. Consider for example [this player](https://www.chess.com/member/dukov5): Replacing 'gmwso' with the player's username will yield a weird output. i imagine the output will be messier for mixed chess960 and chess.